# Mikona Tablet Factory Reset

Tags: factory-reset

How do I reset my Mikona Tablet to its factory settings the model of tablet I have does not have volune buttons on the side of the tablet. Any ideas?

Regards

Mark

Comment: What's the model of your Mikona Tablet? any references may help other people giving you the best answer.
Is it working now or not? means can you access your system right now?